# How can I create a custom application launcher under 32 bit Mint 18 Sara Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, configuration, chrome, cinnamon

Ordinarily I would expect this question to be answered by "Right click on the menu and the menubar and follow your nose," but I've spent quiet a few minutes and searched, and do not see how to manually add Chromium, which seemed not to populate its own icon in the menu or desk.

How can I create a custom menu item and menubar application launcher under 32 bit Mint Sara Cinnamon?

TIA,

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it from repositories via `apt-get` then  it should have created a launcher in `/usr/share/applications` so you could copy that.   Launchers are usually `.desktop` files, which means you can also create one from scratch like so:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Chromium
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
Icon=/path/to/Icon
Terminal=False
```

Save it on desktop as `chromium.desktop` , `Icon=` part is optional.